# Hide image preview on input click/change

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a image preview in JavaScript with some script i found here, I'm new to JS and now I am trying to replace the content instead of appending it. Here is the code

I've tried to put `empty()`, `replaceWith()`, `remove()`,  just before `appendTo()` like other similar questions on SO, I've tried to create a function to hide the div, and nothing seems to work. I was wondering if anyone would know why these functions doesn't work, Am i doing something wrong?

```
//my html/php

echo '<input required type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" multiple 
id="image_upload" accept=".jpg, .jpeg">';
echo '<div id="gallery-preview" class="gallery-preview"></div>';

//javascript
    $(function() {

        var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {

            if (input.files) {

                var filesAmount = input.files.length;

                for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {

                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = function(event) {

                        $($.parseHTML('<img style="width:150px; height:75px; margin-left:2px; margin-right:2px; border:1px solid black; padding:2px;">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
                }
            }
        };
        $('#image_upload').on('change', function() {
            imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery-preview');
        });
    });
```

When i create a function to `hide()` the div `gallery-preview`, the preview doesn't work anymore. Same for other functions mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to set it empty each time you run the function.
Modify the change function in your code to the following

```
 $('#image_upload').on('change', function() {
        //this line will set the contents to empty before you run your function
        $('div.gallery-preview').html('');

        //now call your function  
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery-preview');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! that's all i needed. I feel dumb now.

Comment: well we don't know what we don't know until we know. :)